# RGB LED Arcade Button rewiring for the AIY Google Voice Bonnet

Tags: led

I'd like to rewire an arcade-type RGB button so the button action is
replaced by a simple external push button and the LED function is either
maintained as is or replaced by a single LED.  My button comes with the AIY
Google Voice Bonnet and is attached with 6 pins to an 8 pin harness
as illustrated in the schematic at 
https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice/#makers-guide--button-connector-pinout.  Eventually, my aim is to
replace the new button by a  dialer microswitch as in Alasdair Allen's
retro telephone project, 
https://medium.com/@aallan/a-retro-rotary-phone-powered-by-aiy-projects-and-the-raspberry-pi-e516b3ff1528.  (Note: I have V2 of the
Voice Kit while Alasdair had V1, which has a simpler (4 pin) button.)
At first I thought I could simply remove the leads from the button connected 
by the harness to the BTN and 5V pins and insert a push button as a prototype.
This did not work.  My second attempt simply connected the push button,
220 Ohm resistor and an LED to the GND and 5V pins.  This produced the
expected effect of lighting up the led when the button was pushed, but
didn't communicate with Voice Bonnet as intended by the python code below.
If I want the LED to mimic the RGB LED in the button I need connections
to the BTN and one of the RGB pins, but how?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from aiy.board import Board, Led

def main():
    print('LED is ON while button is pressed (Ctrl-C for exit).')
    with Board() as board:
        while True:
            board.button.wait_for_press()
            print('ON')
            board.led.state = Led.ON
            board.button.wait_for_release()
            print('OFF')
            board.led.state = Led.OFF

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm obviously a total novice at this sort of thing.
An inquiry to the Google AIY team yielded the
advice that I should use the extension pins of the Voice Bonnet 
rather than the existing button pins, but I'd prefer to reserve
these for the on/off-the-hook switch of the phone.  Any advice 
would be much appreciated.

Comment: why do you believe that the switch is connected between BTN and 5V?

Comment: Frankly, I have absolutely no evidence for this whatsoever.

Comment: i am understanding this ... the RGB button is on an end of a wire harness ...  the wire harness plugs into the 8 pin connector on the board .... if that is correct, then depress the button and measure the resistance between the BTN pin and GND ... release the button ... if the resistance does not change, then measure between BTN and +5 .... do this with the button unplugged from the board

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a multimeter,  but will try to get one, as I said I'm a complete novice.  However, perhaps foolishly, I tried detaching the BTN and GND wires from the button connecting them in my tiny breadboard to my push-button.  With this configuration, the button demo in my original post still did not work, but the LED demo did produce the same sequence of flashing colors and dimming as if all the button wiring were connected.

Comment: Finally have a multimeter,  the resistance does change with the button pressed when BTN and GND are connected, but does not change when BTN and 5V are connected.  However, the magnitude of the change is hard to read. In the BTN GND case is the harness supposed to be plugged into the board?